# How to convert Central time to browser time zone in angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

As per my project structure, I always receive CST time zone from database,
But I should show browser time zone in UI.

I need to create custom Pipe to format time

How to convert?

Ex: Received date and time from database - "2021-09-01T03:13:00.300Z" (CST)

Consider my browser timezone as IST

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by adding another parameter for the timezone according to
https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

2021-09-01T03:13:00.30**0Z**
0Z at the end of the date says it is a UTC date.
The difference between UTC and IST is -5 hours.

```
to = new DatePipe('en-Us').transform('2021-09-01T03:13:00.300Z', 'dd:MM:yyyy hh-mm-ss', 'IST');
```

The output of `to` is `31.08.2021 09:13:00` which is right.

So, your input date is in UTC timezone, using the method `transform` you can convert the date in any zone.

Comment: But its not converting correctly, If we converting 2021-09-01T03:13:00.300Z (CST) to IST it should be 2021-09-02 12:30AM but i am getting 08/04/2021 8:43 AM